# Feature Test in Laravel 8 uses withHeader to set Host invalid?

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-8, symfony-http-foundation

Since my project has deployed multiple domain names, the API interface that needs to be tested is using the `api.example.test` domain name as the entrance.

Using `$this->get('/v1/ping')` in Feature Test will request to `www.example.test`, I hope to set up `$this->withHeader('Host', config('domain.api_domain'))` uniformly in `setUp` in `ApiFeatureBaseTestCase` to automatically request API related tests to `api.example.test` Go in.

However, in practice, I found that this is invalid. By tracing the code, I found two codes that may cause the invalid Host setting:

First place (Laravel):

Code in Laravel Framework [src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:503](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L503), pass the parameter `$uri ='/v1/ping'` into `$this->prepareUrlForRequest($uri)` and get a complete Url with the default Host, the return value is `http://www.example.test/v1/ping`.

Second place  (Symfony):

In the code of Symfony HttpFoundation Component [Request.php:355](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/5.x/Request.php#L355), the parsing in `$uri` will be used first The coming out `host` is overwritten in the Header as the default `Host`.

The above two codes eventually caused the `Host` I set by `withHeader` to fail. Obviously, in this code logic, Symfony HttpFoundation Component's choice of Host in conflict cannot be considered wrong, but I submitted this question [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/35281) was closed when it was given to Laravel Framework.

> I don't know if this issue is a `bug` or `feature`?

Finally, I am sorry that my question has interrupted everyone's time, but if there is a conclusion on this question, please tell me what should be more appropriate?

My current approach is `$this->get($this->api_base_url . '/v1/ping')`, but I don’t think this is `elegant`

3Q!!1

### Code example

```php
// File: config/domain.php
return [
    'api_domain' => 'api.example.test',
    'web_domain' => 'www.example.test',
];

// File: routes/demo.php
Route::domain(config('domain.api_domain'))
     ->middleware(['auth:api', 'api.sign.check'])
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(function () {
         Route::get('/v1/ping', function () {
             return 'This Api v1';
         });
     });

Route::domain(config('domain.web_domain'))
     ->middleware('web')
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

// File: tests/ApiFeatureBaseTestCase.php
namespace Tests;

class ApiFeatureBaseTestCase extends TestCase
{
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->withHeader('Host', config('domain.api_domain'));
    }
}

// File: tests/Feature/ApiPingTest.php
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\ApiFeatureBaseTestCase;


class ApiPingTest extends ApiFeatureBaseTestCase
{
    public function testPing()
    {
       $this->get('/v1/ping');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you resolve this? Encountered same problem in 2023 )

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered same problem, as we have 3 types of subdomains for application. To resolve this issue you need to change root URL domain which will be used by url generator before it will be used by TestClass:

```
public function setUp(): void
{
        /**
         * We need this to start test application with merchant app type.
         */

        parent::setUp();

        URL::forceRootUrl('http://subdomain.domain.test');
}
```

Now you can call `$this->get('/v1/ping');` without specifying subdomain and it will work properly.

Sadly, but problem with `MakesHttpRequests.php:503` still exists in 2023 and you can't set `host` header from test as you would like.

This also works in parallel tests `php artisan test --parallel --processes=4`

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a wrapper method on your `ApiFeatureBaseTestCase` class?

```
public function get($uri, array $headers = [])
{
    return parent::get(config('domain.api_domain') . $uri, $headers);
}
```

Then in your `ApiPingTest` class:

```
public function testPing()
{
    $this->get('/v1/ping');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's also a good suggestion, but... I need to also define other functions like `get` `post` `getJson` `postJson` (if I will use it)